# A query for getting results separated by a date gap

Tags: mysql, sql

| ID | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 12:00:00 |
| 2 | 2020-02-01 12:00:00 |
| 3 | 2020-05-01 12:00:00 |
| 4 | 2020-06-01 12:00:00 |
| 5 | 2020-07-01 12:00:00 |

---

I am looking for a way to get records in a MySQL database that are within a certain range of each other. In the above example, notice that there is a month between the first two records, then a three month gap, before we see another three records with a month between.

What is a way to group these into two result sets, so I will get Ids `1, 2` and `3, 4, 5` A solution using days would be probably work the best as thats easier to modify.

Comment: If you show us some ways, we can tell you which is best. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: This does not seem to be a very simple query for me. Unfortunately I cannot provide an example, as I have absolutely no clue where to start on this one, which is why I come here, hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: But you know how to construct CREATE and INSERT statements, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and then logic to see where a gap is big enough to start a new set of records.  A cumulative sum gives you the groups you want:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_timestamp >= timestamp - interval 1 month then 0 else 1 end) over (order by timestamp) as grouping
from (select t.*,
             lag(timestamp) over (order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp
      from t
     ) t;
```

If you want to summarize this with a start and end date:

```
select min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_timestamp >= timestamp - interval 1 month then 0 else 1 end) over (order by timestamp) as grouping
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(timestamp) over (order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by grouping;
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, the following query:

```
select group_concat(ID)
from (
  select w1.ID,w1.TS,w2.ID flag
  from work1 w1 left outer join work1 w2
  on timestampdiff(month,w2.TS,w1.TS)=1
  order by w1.ID
) w
group by
  case when flag is null then @str:=ID else @str end
```

See [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hXzbyEMEH9U1N8Yz49YA9P/0)